# Is it possible to setup a web tab in Salesforce which will go to this KB without needing to login using username and password?

Tags: authentication, rest

We have a Web KB that is built in PHP.  Is it possible to setup a web tab in Salesforce which will go to this KB without needing to login using username and password?

I initially thought that SAML may help and that I can use salesforce as identity provider.  However,  the Service Provider PHPKB does not support SAML.

I am thinking of getting session ID from salesforce and pass it to KB for autohentincation.

However, I don't know how to do it. just a theory

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple approaches possible depending on what level of configurability/ code access you have on the PHP side and how you want to integrate with Salesforce.

1. There's a [PHP Toolkit for Force.com](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP) which supports multiple authentication schemes including LDAP, Radius, Active Directory etc. This [link](http://epixa.com/2010/05/php-integration-with-salesforce-crm.html) provides a good tutorial on how to deal with auth part when integrating an external PHP app with Salesforce.
2. There's also an option to use Force.com Canvas for your external PHP applications. Canvas apps usually authenticate via either oAuth or signed requests. You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/02/using-php-for-canvas-applications.html).

If you have tried these and are facing any issues, please let me know and I may be able to help further.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response,  I am considering using Canvas.  It appears that Salesforce using Canvass can provide a consumer secret to use for authentication.  My problem is I am not knowledgable in PHP and I don't know where to set this Consumer secret.  Does this require extensive coding in PHP side?